# Can you set auto deletion for every bucket and every future bucket on MinIO

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, minio, ilm, s3-lifecycle-policy

I'm using MinIO and want to set a service-wide lifecycle policy that will delete every bucket that's old than a specific period of time (In my case it's 1 day).

I also want this policy to work on buckets that will be created at the future

I wonder if I can do that and how

Thanks in advance for everyone who will help

Answer (score 1):

Set up a service-wide lifecycle policy in MinIO to delete the s3 buckets older than a specific period of time such as 5 days, 10 days, or 25 days this policy also applied to the future s3 buckets as well.

The day's attribute determines the number of days after that specified number of days the object will transfer into the Glacier storage class.

```
<LifecycleConfiguration>
  <Rule>
    <ID>rule-id</ID>
    <Status>Enabled</Status>
    <Filter>
      <Prefix></Prefix>
    </Filter>
    <Transition>
      <Days>25</Days>
      <StorageClass>GLACIER</StorageClass>
    </Transition>
  </Rule>
</LifecycleConfiguration>
```